# Dafny - Specifying that the largest element less than a given element is returned

Tags: specifications, verification, dafny, formal-verification

### Goal

I wrote a method `GetPredecessor(x, s)` which takes a real number `x` and a sorted sequence of reals `s`.
The input `x` is not necessarily a member of the sequence, but it is greater than or equal to the smallest member of the sequence, and less than or equal to the largest member of the sequence.

The output is supposed to be the largest member of the sequence that is less than the input (if possible).

#### Example

Let `s = [1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0]`.

- For `3.0 < x <= 4.0` (e.g. `x = 3.2`, `x = 3.8`, `x = 4.0`), the output shall be `3.0` (not `1.0` or `2.0`).
- For `x = 1.0` there is no element in the sequence less than `x`, so the output shall be `1.0`.

### Question

I have been able to specify all preconditions and the following postconditions:

- if the input is equal to the smallest element of the sequence, return that
- if the input is larger than the smallest element of the sequence, the output will be less than the input

which is why the following assertions hold

```
var s := [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0];
var r := 0.0;

r := GetPredecessor(1.0, s);
assert r == 1.0; // OK

r := GetPredecessor(3.2, s);
assert r <= 3.0; // OK
```

I have been unable to write the following postcondition:

- the output will be the largest element smaller than the input

which is why this assertion does not hold:

```
r := GetPredecessor(3.2, s);
assert r == 3.0; // FAILS
```

What do I need to do to specify the behaviour explained above, and how do I need to change the method body for the postcondition to hold on all return paths in the method?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Code

#### Predicates and functions used in specifications

```
predicate Sorted(s: seq<real>)
{
    forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < |s| ==> s[i] < s[j]
}

predicate Distinct(s: seq<real>)
{
    forall i,j :: 0 <= i < |s| && 0 <= j < |s| && i != j ==> s[i] != s[j]
}

function method Min(s: seq<real>) : (m: real)
    requires |s| > 0 && Sorted(s)
    ensures m in s
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> m <= s[i]
    ensures exists i :: 0 <= i < |s| && m == s[i]
{
    s[0]
}

function method Max(s: seq<real>) : (m: real)
    requires |s| > 0 && Sorted(s)
    ensures m in s
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> m >= s[i]
    ensures exists i :: 0 <= i < |s| && m == s[i]
{
    s[|s| - 1]
}
```

#### Main method / functionality

```
// returns the largest element in the sequence s that is smaller than input x; or Min(s), if x is Min(s)
method GetPredecessor(x: real, s: seq<real>) returns (r: real)
    requires |s| > 0 && Sorted(s) && Distinct(s)
    requires Min(s) <= x <= Max(s)
    ensures r in s
    ensures x == Min(s) ==> r == Min(s)
    ensures x != Min(s) ==> r < x
    // TODO: add postcondition -> not just any "predecessor" is returned, rather the largest of them
    {
        if x == Min(s)
        {
            return x;
        }

        var i := 0;
        r := s[i];

        while i < |s|
            invariant 0 <= i <= |s|
            invariant r in s
            invariant r < x
            decreases |s| - i
        {
            if r < s[i] < x
            {
                r := s[i];
            }

            i := i + 1;
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this predicate:

```
predicate LargestSmaller(x: real, s: seq<real>, returned: real)
{ 
  && returned in s
  && forall i | 0 <= i < |s| ::
        s[i] > returned ==> s[i] > x
}
```

Here is how you'd use it in your method definition:

```
method GetPredecessor(x: real, s: seq<real>) returns (r: real)
  ...
  ensures x != Min(s) ==> LargestSmaller(x, s, r)
```

Because you have a forall, you need to explicitly trigger it it if you want to prove your point:

```
      r := GetPredecessor(3.2, s);
      assert r == 1.0 || r == 2.0 || r == 3.0;
      var _, _ := s[1], s[2]; // Automatically instantiate the predicate to prove that r != 1.0 and r != 2.0, otherwise you'd get a contradiction.
      assert r == 3.0; // SUCCEEDS
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. Just a few questions where I would be happy if you were able to address them. (1) Why do you use `&& returned in s` instead of `returned in s`? (2) What does it mean to "automatically instantiate the predicate"? Why do we need to retrieve `s[1]` and `s[2]` at all? Do we not need to retrieve `s[0]` because it is `Min(s)`? Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) Because Dafny supports && like a bullet point list, which makes it easier to see each conjunct (2) see Dafny triggers https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-trigger